# Can Googlebot discover URLs that are not in an anchor?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, crawl-errors

In my Search Console I had a sudden increase in 404's.
They were linked from a webpage that listed files from the site in a table but none of these URLs were nested inside an `<a>` tag.

This was the only instance of the URLs I could find on the page which led me to question, does Google still follow a url string even if it's not in an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they do crawl everything that looks like a URL. I have made a test (in German, but red="not crawled" and green="crawled"): http://www.sirpauls.com/welchen-links-folgt-google-ein-experiment/

Google crawled stuff like

```
<script>var test="www.example.net/page.html";</script>
```

or simply

```
www.example.net/page.html
```

So i think they only look for a URL patterns.

Comment: It is worth adding that it is unclear if Google assigns value (link juice or Pagerank) to the non-anchor links.     Also, 404 errors listed in search console won't hurt your site as long as you don't expect to have content on those URLs.   There can be a million 404 URLs caused by this problem and Google won't penalize your site in any way.

Comment: Good effort! However, I don't see an example of your first one (JS comment) in your list of tests? In fact, you later state, "Comments and CDATA blocks Google seems to ignore completely." _(Google translated)_ Also, all the "successfully crawled" URLs in your test appear to be full absolute URLs. Whereas the examples listed above (`www.example.net`) are technically _relative_. (?)

Comment: @w3dk you are right, i wrote it out of memory, i edited the answer

Comment: ...and what about the relative/absolute difference?

Comment: In my experience, Googlebot will try to crawl any string with a slash embedded in the middle, or any string that ends in ".html".  So Googlebot crawls *some* relative URLs that it finds in JavaScript or page text.